# Regular expression match between string and last digit

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression matches the text in bold in all the examples.

Between the string "JZ" and any character before "-"

`JZ123456789-301A`
`JZ134255872-22013`

Between the string "JZ" and the last character

`JZ123456789D`

I have tried the following but it only works for the first example

```
(?<=JZ).*(?=-)
```

Comment: Try `(?<=JZ)[^-]*(?=-|.$)`

Comment: does it need to be a regular expression? I imagine you could do the same thing splitting on `-` and only using records which start with `JZ`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's not matching JZ188640882D correctly

Comment: @AlexW Yes I do need a regular expression.  I agree it would be easier to do in C#.  I added the C# tag to indicate the flavor of regex, not that I can use the language itself.

Comment: @Robert [It matches `188640882`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dJZ%29%5b%5e-%5d*%28%3f%3d-%7c.%24%29&i=JZ188640882D&o=m) - and what do you expect? It matches exactly what you asked for: all after `JZ` and up to the first hyphen or up to the last char in the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My mistake, it does match correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
JZ([^-]*)(?:-|.$)
```

and grab Group 1 value. See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=JZ%28%5b%5e-%5d*%29%28%3f%3a-%7c.%24%29&i=JZ123456789-301A%0d%0aJZ134255872-22013%0d%0aJZ123456789D&o=m).

**Details**

- `JZ` - a literal substring
- `([^-]*)` - Capturing group 1: zero or more chars other than `-`
- `(?:-|.$)` - a non-capturing group matching either `-` or any char at the end of the string

C# code:

```
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"JZ([^-]*)(?:-|.$)");
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

If, for some reason, you need to obtain the required value as a whole match, use lookarounds:

```
(?<=JZ)[^-]*(?=-|.$)
```

See [this regex variation demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3DJZ%29%5B%5E-%5D*%28%3F%3D-%7C.%24%29&i=JZ123456789-301A%0D%0AJZ134255872-22013%0D%0AJZ123456789D&o=m). Use `m.Value` in the code above to grab the value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `(?<=JZ)[0-9]+`, presuming the desired text will always be numeric.

[Try it out here](https://regex101.com/r/7NCFuf/1)

Answer (score 0):

A one-line answer without regex:

```
string s,r;

// if your string always starts with JZ
s = "JZ123456789-301A";
r = string.Concat(s.Substring(2).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit));
Console.WriteLine(r); // output : 123456789

// if your string starts with anything
s = "A12JZ123456789-301A";
r = string.Concat(s.Substring(s.IndexOf("JZ")).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit));
Console.WriteLine(r); // output : 123456789
```

Basically, we remove everything before and including the delimiter "JZ", then we take each char while they are digit. The `Concat` is use to transform the `IEnumerable<char>` to a string. I think it is easier to read.

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KKGC7s)